# Discord.net my bot can't send audio in voice channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

What I'm trying to make is sending mp3 file in voice channel using command
Evertything is ok but on FlushAsync it's not working

here is my command

```
[Command("tts", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
        public async Task Say()
        {
            IAudioClient audioClient = TTSBot.AudioClient;

            // await ReplyAsync($"tts!");
            string text = Context.Message.ToString().Substring(1);
            MakeTTS(text);
            string path = Path.GetFullPath("tts.mp3");

           // if (audioClient != null)
           //     Console.WriteLine("Not null");

            await SendAsync(audioClient, path);
            await Task.Delay(1000);

        }
```

and methods for ffmpeg and sending audio

```
        public async Task SendAsync(IAudioClient client, string path)
        {         
            var ffmpeg = CreateStream(path);
            var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            var discord = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed);
            await output.CopyToAsync(discord);
            await discord.FlushAsync();
        }

        private Process CreateStream(string path)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ffmpeg = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",
                Arguments = $@"-hide_banner  -loglevel debug -i ""{path}"" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1 ",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            };
            return Process.Start(ffmpeg);
        }
```

and here's console window

```
[mp3 @ 00000109d5575ac0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'tts.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, s16le, to 'pipe:1':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 pcm_s16le
size=     118kB time=00:00:00.62 bitrate=1536.0kbits/s speed=  20x
video:0kB audio:118kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
```

I found some codes but can't fix this problem

is there a problem in using ffmpeg or other things?
anyone can help to fix it?